# Save limit change when adding another filter

Tags: php, jquery, joomla, get

Im lost here, and need advice. My situation: with folowing code I change default items limit in module:

```
<form method="get" style="text-align:center;">
            <input type="hidden" name="lastrecepes" value="">
                <button type="submit" value="24" id="limit" name="limit" onclick="change();" style="width:200px;margin:20px 0 20px 0;"/>change limit</button>
                <script>
                function change(){
                var elem = document.getElementById("limit");
                if (elem.value=="24") elem.value = "36";}
                </script>

            </form>
```

helper.php:

```
public static function getLists(&$params)
    {
        $total_items = ($_GET['limit']) ? $_GET['limit'] : $params->get('count');
        if ($_GET['limit']) $params->set('count',$_GET['limit']);
            $content_source = $params->get('content_source','joomla');

    }
```

my link changes to: http:***/project/?lastrecepes=&limit=36
and it works, but when im trying to add another filter like:

```
<button type="submit" value="0" id="skip_items" name="skip_items" onclick="change1();" style="width:200px;margin:20px 0 20px 0;"/>more</button><script>
                function change1(){
                var elem = document.getElementById("skip_items");
                if (elem.value=="0") elem.value = "15";}
                </script>
```

it changes limit to old value, and url looks like: http:***/project/?lastrecepes=&skip_items=15

If i manually add those together they work fine: http:***/project/?lastrecepes=&limit=36&skip_items=15

can anyone help me with it, i dlike to save first filtering result when another filter comes in. Sorry for my bad english hope u can understand me.

Comment: can this be so hard? no1 knows?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well of course the limit will change back from 36 to 24 when you refresh the page, because you are not saving the change anywhere. If You go to `http:*/project/?lastrecepes=&skip_items=15`, the limit is 24, because that is the default value.

What you have to do is save the limit to a cookie or a session (depending on your needs) when you change it and then check the cookie / session every time when page loads for a current limit value.

Comment: ok, i get it, is there a chance ud give me some example how to do that?

Comment: Sorry, but that would involve some time, which i'm not able to invest. Please google for PHP cookies and try it by yourself . If you are not familiar with it at all, it would probably take couple of hours.